# How to get jenkins to deploy .war file to tomcat6 not localhost

Tags: maven, deployment, jenkins, tomcat6, pom.xml

I have a jenkins ci that builds our projects and make a .war file of it.
But i can´t get it to deploy to jenkins, how do i do that?

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>MavenWeb</groupId>
<artifactId>MavenWeb</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<description></description>
<distributionManagement>
<repository>
  <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
  <id>e-ject.se</id>
  <name>e-ject.se</name>
  <url>http://e-ject.se/MavenWeb</url>
  <layout>default</layout>
</repository>
 </distributionManagement>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-beta-1</version>
                <configuration>
    <url>http://e-ject.se:8080/manager</url>
    <server>e-ject.se</server>
    <path>/MavenWeb</path>
</configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

And i added all info in settings.xml i found on the web. I can login to e-ject.se:8080/manager/html with the username and password.

```
<server>
    <id>e-ject.se</id>
    <username>jonathan</username>
    <password>*****</password>
    <filePermissions>664</filePermissions>
    <directoryPermissions>775</directoryPermissions>
    <configuration></configuration>
</server>
```

I get this in the jenkins console:

```
mavenExecutionResult exceptions not empty
message : Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy     (default-deploy) on project MavenWeb: 
Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact   MavenWeb:MavenWeb:war:0.0.1-20120412.150346-1 from/to e-ject.se 
(http://e-ject.se/MavenWeb): Failed to transfer file: http://e-ject.se/MavenWeb/MavenWeb/MavenWeb/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/MavenWeb-0.0.1-20120412.150346-1.war. 
Return code is: 405
```

If i just add tomcat:deploy in jenkins instead of deploy

i get:

```
 mavenExecutionResult exceptions not empty
 message : Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli)     on project MavenWeb: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
 cause : Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
```

and later:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL:   http://localhost:8080/manager/deploy?path=%2FMavenWeb&war=
```

Can someone please help me get this to work, i have read a ton of guides but i cannot get it to work!

Regard
Jonathan

Comment: 401 is an authentication error. I suspect that either your tomcat instance doesn't have the manager app enabled or more likely you haven't configured it with a user and password to match your Maven settings file.

Comment: I can reach the manager/html with the user and password and the user is both admin and manager. So the manager is working and i can deploy by upload, but not by jenkins... thx for your answer!

Comment: How do i mark you comment as answer? I realized i had more than one jenkins installed maven and i had previouse installations that mislead me!

Comment: How to answer your own question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized i had more than one jenkins installed maven and i had previouse installations that misslead me! Sometimes its just better to just start over and do it right.